# Patch.crates-io is not applied

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am using serde-xml-rs crate in our project and I need to modify some code from that crate, so what I did is to generate a patch file, and apply it by calling `cargo patch`. In my Cargo.toml has stuff like following:

```
serde-xml-rs = "0.6.0"

[package.metadata.patch.serde-xml-rs]
version = "0.6.0"
patches = [
    "patches/0001.patch"
]
[patch.crates-io]
serde-xml-rs = { path = "./target/patch/serde-xml-rs-0.6.0" }
```

When I called `cargo run`, project still use original version of serde-xml-rs instead of using values in patch.crates-io tag

But I could see that my patch is applied correctly to the target folder "./target/patch/serde-xml-rs-0.6.0", because if I modify toml file to following, it worked.

```
{ path = "./target/patch/serde-xml-rs-0.6.0" }
```

Comment: Just noticed that there is a warning, but I do not know what does it mean exactly.  warning: replace for the non root package will be ignored, specify replace at the workspace root

Comment: You need to put the `patch` in the workspace's Cargo.toml, not for the individual package.

Comment: It is not very clear for me how to add patch in the wrokspace's cargo.toml. It says "No patches found" if I simply move patch section to the top of the root cargo.toml file.